# Spring boot. How to put array to json

Tags: java, json, spring

For example I want to get such JSON in response in my Spring boot application:

```
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "453 123-1234",
       "753 123-4567"
   ]
}
```

I have @Entity annotated class:

```
@Entity 
public class MyEntity { 

String firstName; 
String lastNAme;
String phoneNumbers;

//constructors, getters and setters... 
}
```

Then if I send request to endpoint, I get such response:

```
{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"phoneNumbers": "453 123-1234, 753 123-4567"
}
```

where phoneNumbers is just a string, but not an array.
I tried different variants of designing of phoneNumbers field, as array or collection, and use annotations, for example @ElementCollection, but only exceptions or error messages came back after requests.
How to resolve this question?

Comment: You have to make an array out of them. First, when you declared String phonenumbers you are declaring it as a single String. Try String[] phoneNumbers; You will also need to change your getters and setters, constructors accordingly.

Comment: if you can change the field name, you can create another field and which would split this string into a array and return that

Comment: have you tried to define them as List? they should work, what are the exception you have got?

Answer (score 3):

You need a list for your phone numbers

```
public class MyEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastNAme;
    private List<String> phoneNumbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a good design of database

- Every individual entity should have a primary key.
- If it contains a **multivalued attribute** then bring out and make it
  as a **new entity** with foreign key reference to parent entity.

These relational entities should have columns similar as below

```
ParentEntity 
entity_id   first_name  last_name

PhoneNumber
child_id    entity_id   phone_number
```

with these mapping configurations in the model classes

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    private long entityId;
    private String firstName; 
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentEntity")
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
}

@Entity
public class PhoneNumber { 
    @Id
    private long childId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityId")
    private ParentEntity parentEntity
    private int phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the same db structure. I perform specific query to my DB (with joins, group by and group_concat() functions), which allow to store multiple values [i.e. phone_number] from second table in one cell of result set for each record.